# Unix grep, sed, awk commands to find average response time of a request from log files

Tags: unix, awk, sed, grep

The requirement is to find average response time for an API call from a bunch of log files.
From log files, I would like to filter pick logs of pattern:

`Eligible programs received from program service for user '89e45876-6ae7-2d08-217c-7320aada1a3d' in 840 ms.`

And then take average of all the response times.

I came up with below code using grep, sed and awk commands, which is printing average response time for each log file.

```
for file in *; do 
    if [ -f "$file" ]; then 
        cat $file | grep ".*Eligible programs received from program service for user .*" | sed -E -n "s/.*Eligible programs received from program service for user .* in (.*) ms.*/\\1/p" | awk '{ SUM += $1; COUNT += 1;} END { print SUM/COUNT }'
    fi 
done
```

But I want a single average value computed for all log files. How can I modify above program to achieve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here's how to do both tasks (per file and total) at once robustly if you don't have too many files to fit in the awk arg list:

```
#!/bin/env bash

IFS=$'\n' read -r -d '' -a files < <(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f && printf '\0')

awk '
/Eligible programs received from program service for user/ {
    sum[FILENAME] += $(NF-1)
    cnt[FILENAME]++
}
END {
    for (i=1; i<ARGC; i++) {
        file = ARGV[i]
        print file, (cnt[file] ? sum[file] / cnt[file] : 0)
        tot_sum += sum[file]
        tot_cnt += cnt[file]
    }
    print "TOTAL", (tot_cnt ? tot_sum / tot_cnt : 0)
}
' "${files[@]}"
```

The above will work with any awk and will handle rainy day scenarios such as having directories in the same directory as your files or files without the target string gracefully.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to take average file by file then could you please try following(with GNU `awk`), Thanks to @Jotne for pointing out for count="".

```
awk '
/Eligible programs received from program service for user/{
  sum+=$(NF-1)
  count++
}
ENDFILE{
  print "Avg=" sum/count
  count=sum=""
}
' /path/to/your/files/*
```

---

---

***EDIT:*** In case you want average for all files then try:

```
awk '
/Eligible programs received from program service for user/{
  sum+=$(NF-1)
  count++
}
END{
  print "Avg=" sum/count
}
' /path/to/your/files/*
```

Comment: Ravinder Singh, thank you for prompt response.
It's not working. The same command works for single file though. Below command works:
`awk '/Eligible programs received from program service for user/{
  sum+=$(NF-1);
  count++
} END { print sum/count }' recommendationservice.log.2019-09-27`

Comment: `ENDFILE` is the wrong command to use, it will give the average response for each file, but `END` will give the average for all files.  And if you like the average for one and one file, the counter should be set to zero after printing the avg.

Comment: @Jotne, Thanks, honestly I thought user needs avg for one by one files, will edit the answer now.

Comment: @Sreenivas, yes that's what I thought that you need file by file avg, if that is not the case then END will work for awk code.

Comment: It was wrong for file by file as well.  You need this for all file `END{print "Avg="sum/count}` or for each file `ENDFILE {print "Avg="sum/count;cunt=0}`

Comment: @Jotne, I want one average value of all files together, not one by one for each file. And both `END` and `ENDFILE` are not helpful in achieving it.

Comment: @Sreenivas, Are you sure you are using these codes with GNU `awk` version  4+ kindly check version of your `awk` once too by doing `awk --version`, I added 2 different codes now 1st for each file avg and 2nd for total avg and both should work IMHO.

Comment: @Sreenivas, Also make sure you DO NOT have any control M characters in your files, check it by doing `cat -v Input_file` and if you find them then we need to tweak code a bit then, let me know?

Comment: @Sreenivas  average total works fine with `END`, but `ENDFILE` average for each file, still does not work, `sum` needs to be reset as well, so some my fault above, correct should be `ENDFILE {print "Avg="sum/count;sum=cunt=0}`  So this is why I always (if possible) post output of my answer.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 I have `GNU Awk 3.1.7` version. It might work on version 4 as you mentioned. Thank you for the help.